# Additional text to reference

Tags: cross-referencing

Can I add additional text for reference?
The text (arrow here) should be placed before or after the page number, depending on the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{reference}


\begin{document}
Hello1
\label{hello1}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Helo2, see \pageref{hello1} or \pageref{hello3} or \pageref{hello4} \newline
Desired output: Hello2, see ($\leftarrow$\pageref{hello1}), (\pageref{hello3}$\rightarrow$),(\pageref{hello4}$\rightarrow$)
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Hello3
\label{hello3}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Hello4
\label{hello4}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just create your own reference command: `\newcommand{\arrpageref}[1]{($\leftarrow$\pageref{#1})}` and use it: `\arrpageref{hello1}`.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan How to determinate if current page number is greater then \pageref? In this case put $\leftarrow$ before \pageref.
If current page number is less than \pageref put $\rightarrow$ after \pageref.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that you want to use different symbols depending on where the referenced page is located. Then more complicated approach is necessary indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `refcount` package that provides the command `\getpagerefnumber`. This command (unlike the normal `\pageref`) can be used for numerical comparisons, for example using the built-in `\ifnum` tests. The code below tests for three cases: before the current page (left arrow), at current page (no arrow) and after the current page (right arrow).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{reference}
\newcommand{\arrpageref}[1]{%
(\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{#1}=\value{page}%
\pageref{#1}\else%
\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{#1}>\value{page}%
\pageref{#1}\textrightarrow\else%
\textleftarrow\pageref{#1}\fi\fi)}

\begin{document}
Hello1
\label{hello1}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\label{hello2}
Hello2, see \pageref{hello1} or \pageref{hello3} or \pageref{hello4} \newline
Desired output: Hello2, see ($\leftarrow$\pageref{hello1}), (\pageref{hello3}$\rightarrow$),(\pageref{hello4}$\rightarrow$)\newline
Hello2, see \arrpageref{hello1} or \arrpageref{hello2} or \arrpageref{hello3} or \arrpageref{hello4} \newline
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Hello3
\label{hello3}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Hello4
\label{hello4}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nitpicking: you can remove `\relax` after `\value{page}` (but keep `%`)

Comment: Also `\textleftarrow` and `\textrightarrow`

Comment: @egreg thanks for the comments, I edited them in.